# Firebase configuration, version 9.22.0

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've heard that in the latest version of firebase the syntax for importing and exporting has changed a lot so in my config.js file i want to make it configure

// config.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { addDoc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";



//  web app's Firebase configuration
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api key",
  authDomain: "auth domain",
  projectId: "project id",
  storageBucket: "blah blah blah",
  messagingSenderId: "00000000000",
  appId: "hidden, buhahaha"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);


export default app;
```

The following code is giving the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_firestore.js?v=249c158b' does not provide an export named 'addDoc' (at config.js?t=1690093124329:3:10)

and the website page is displaying as a blank page.